# Know if a live domain would redirect to https or not

Tags: php, curl, https

I'd been working out all night to know what function should I use (basically running around cURL and DOM).

I would always be given with domain only, sometimes SSL enabled, that is, say paypal.com. But going to paypal.com would redirect me to https://paypal.com which is great.

What I want is, given the domain, know if that website will redirect me to https or non-https

Here is the working I currently have, it is cURL, if you have any other idea that would be great. Actually, I would prefer solutions using DOM since I'd been using DOM in my entire script.

```
$a = 'paypal.com';
$b = "http://" . $a . "/";
$url = $b; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
echo "Original: $url <br>Final: $lastUrl";
exit;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the port by `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` if you get port `"443"` it means URL is SSL enabled.
you can try like this

```
if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=="443"){
         $domain = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
       }else{
         $domain = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
       }
echo $domain;
```

Hope it should work for you..